# Como fazer um loop dentro de uma pasta de imagens e redimensioná-las?

Tags: php, funções, processamento-de-imagens

Eu tenho essa **[classe em PHP](http://pastebin.com/HWtgvwMU)** que ao rodar redimensiona as imagens contidas em uma pasta. Se vocês observarem, o redimensionamento é disparado por estas instruções, uma para cada tamanho desejado.

```
resize_and_crop('banner.jpg', 'banner_100x100.jpg', 100, 100);
resize_and_crop('banner.jpg', 'banner_200x100.jpg', 200, 100);
resize_and_crop('banner.jpg', 'banner_200x300.jpg', 200, 300);
```

A função completa está no **[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/HWtgvwMU)** e ela redimensiona perfeitamente em 3 cópias a imagem original, cada uma de um tamanho diferente conforme foi determinado no uso da função `resize_and_crop()`. Vou colocar o arquivo pra rodar dentro da pasta das imagens, então não precisa de caminhos.

Observe que a `function` aguarda 4 parâmetros:

- nome da imagem atual
- nome da imagem nova
- largura (width)
- altura (height)

**Pergunta:** como fazer um loop  que retorne todas as imagens dessa pasta e dentro deste `loop` aplique a função `resize_and_crop()` para cada uma das imagens retornadas?

```
// RESIZE AN IMAGE PROPORTIONALLY AND CROP TO THE CENTER
function resize_and_crop($original_image_url, $thumb_image_url, $thumb_w, $thumb_h, $quality = 100)
{
    // ACQUIRE THE ORIGINAL IMAGE: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php
    $original = imagecreatefromjpeg($original_image_url);
    if (!$original) return FALSE;

    // GET ORIGINAL IMAGE DIMENSIONS
    list($original_w, $original_h) = getimagesize($original_image_url);

    // RESIZE IMAGE AND PRESERVE PROPORTIONS
    $thumb_w_resize = $thumb_w;
    $thumb_h_resize = $thumb_h;
    if ($original_w > $original_h) ...
```

Este é só um pedaço da function que aparece completa no link externo.

Answer (score 4):

Para retornar todas as imagens dessa pasta, utilize a função **glob**, com o `GLOB_BRACE`, que permite expandir os termos de busca.

```
<?php

$formatos = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif');

foreach(glob('*.{'.implode(',', $formatos).'}', GLOB_BRACE) as $imagem){
    # Aplicar resize_and_crop
    print "Imagem: " . $imagem . "<br/>";
    $thumb = explode('.',$imagem);
    print "Thumbnail: {$thumb[0]}_200x300.{$thumb[1]}<br/>";
}

?>
```

Dentro deste loop, podes simplesmente aplicar a função `resize_and_crop` da seguinte maneira:

```
...
    resize_and_crop($imagem, "{$thumb[0]}_100x100.{$thumb[1]}", 100, 100);
    resize_and_crop($imagem, "{$thumb[0]}_200x100.{$thumb[1]}", 200, 100);
    resize_and_crop($imagem, "{$thumb[0]}_200x300.{$thumb[1]}", 200, 300);
...
```

É bem provável que a tua função não esteja a funcionar como deve ser, porque ela não possui suporte para outros formatos para além do `jpeg`, veja este pequeno [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376315/creating-a-thumbnail-from-an-uploaded-image) que lida com diferentes formatos.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) ou a função [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php)

**Glob()**

```
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $arquivo) {
    $nameWithoutExtensionJPG = str_replace('.jpg', '', $arquivo);
    resize_and_crop($arquivo, $nameWithoutExtensionJPG.'_100x100.jpg', 100, 100);
    resize_and_crop($arquivo, $nameWithoutExtensionJPG.'_200x100.jpg', 200, 100);
    resize_and_crop($arquivo, $nameWithoutExtensionJPG.'_200x300.jpg', 200, 300);
}
```

Obs: tem formas melhores de tirar a extensão do arquivo, usei essa apenas para facilitar.

Comment: Porque será estou recebendo este erro: http://puu.sh/luW4K/3f707f1170.png

Comment: Parece que tem algum arquivo `.jpg` que não é uma imagem `jpg`

Answer (score 3):

Para pegar as imagens de uma pasta e fazer o loop seria alguma coisa assim:

```
$dir = "/var/www/img/*.jpg";
//pega todas as imagens do tipo jpg e coloca dentro de uma array com nome $images
$images = glob( $dir );

//Roda todas as imagens do array $images
foreach( $images as $image ):
    echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />"; // apenas um exemplo de código aqui dentro do loop
    //coloca a função resize_and_crop() aqui dentro.
endforeach;
```

Comment: Porque será estou recebendo este erro: http://puu.sh/luW4K/3f707f1170.png